# SqlParameter Cast in C#

Tags: c#, sql, casting

I have a SqlParameter contained in a var coming back from a stored procedure and the value is either Null, an int or -1.  How do cast the var to check if it is -1 in C#?

```
var p_eventID = new SqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "@EventID",
    Value = (eventID.HasValue
        ? (object)eventID.Value
        : (object)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null),
    Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
};
```

I have tried:

```
if ((int?)eventID.Value == -1)
```

But it gives me an invalid cast error.

Comment: Please show the code where you pull from the SqlParameter.  What is the type of `eventID`?

Comment: What database is your procedure in? Different databases return different types.

Comment: Are you after [DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)??

Comment: Edited question with SqlParameter assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL requests report `NULL`s to C# through [`DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) objects, forcing the cast to fail.

You can do the other kind of cast to `int?` without triggering an error:

```
var eventIdInt = eventId as int?;
if (eventIdInt == -1) {
    ...
}
```

Rather than throwing an exception, the `x as type` style of cast would produce a `null` value when the cast fails.

Comment: Don't you mean `if (eventIdInt.HasValue && eventIdInt.Value == -1)`?  As it's written it could still throw a NullReferenceException on the if statement.

Comment: @ErikPhilips No, you do not need to check `HasValue`: the comparison will succeed if the value is `-1`, and it would not throw an exception when the value is `null`.

Comment: Darn the magic!  You're right, I always check for null for throwing errors, so this code is backwards for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach when an error occurs, it will throw an **Invalid Cast Exception**.  However, if you utilize the `as int` if it fails it will return a *null*.  Which will be a bit more graceful, and forgiving.

So you could do the following:

```
if(eventId != null)
{
     // Do Stuff.
}
```

So that returned value from your scalar, should either contain an actual `int` or a `null`.

So in order to solve why you receive the error with the `(int)` we would need to see how you implement the scalar and know the type of `object` it is actually returning before the cast.